# jQuery Post Inner Workings

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Recently I have been trying to get away from using jQuery for every little task since most of the time all I need to do is submit forms, etc. However when trying to run a simple POST request I noticed that this does not actually get sent to the POST variable since dumping it out when submitting using the following method must be retrieved using file_get_contents('php://input').

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('POST', '/my/url', true);
request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=UTF-8');
request.send(data);
```

However using the built in ajax post in jQuery sends the data to the post variable and can be retrieved using $_POST in my php script. Could anyone explain to me the inner workings of this function https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/ and how they are able to accomplish this.

Thanks

Comment: @AnandSomasekhar don't use w3school please

Comment: @AnandSomasekhar that does not answer my question at all please read it. Your link to w3schools is amusing.

Comment: @mschuett If you want to see how jQuery does something, check the source code. _"I've been trying to get away from using jQuery for every little task"_ - simplifying ajax is probably the best reason to use jQuery.

Comment: [James Padolsey's jQuery source viewer](http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.10.2&fn=$.post) is a convenient way to browse through the jQuery source - it has hyperlinks between function definitions so you don't have to be scrolling up and down or searching manually.

Comment: I know that the inner works is all in the ajax call. Although I can write some javascript I by no means understand the inner workings of that scary ajax function.

Comment: @JasonP thats great and jQuery does a terrific job I am asking how they get around this limitation though. I am far from a front end developer and do very little with javascript which is why i thought you guys might be able to answer this one. However any question that requires indepth knowledge or time never is answered on here. When i get some time this weekend I'll learn a little javascript and let you guys know how it's done so people don't need to load in 200kb of data when they only need to make one simple call that could be done using 1-2 kb of code.

Answer (score 0):

I think the parts you're interested in are this snippet of the `ajax` function, which calls `jQuery.param()` on the passed data if that data isn't a string:

```
// Convert data if not already a string
if ( s.data && s.processData && typeof s.data !== "string" ) {
    s.data = jQuery.param( s.data, s.traditional );
}
```

And `jQuery.param()`, which converts a couple formats (including a javascript object) to a querystring in the format `key1=value1&key2=value2`:

```
// Serialize an array of form elements or a set of
// key/values into a query string
jQuery.param = function( a, traditional ) {
    var prefix,
        s = [],
        add = function( key, value ) {
            // If value is a function, invoke it and return its value
            value = jQuery.isFunction( value ) ? value() : ( value == null ? "" : value );
            s[ s.length ] = encodeURIComponent( key ) + "=" + encodeURIComponent( value );
        };

    // Set traditional to true for jQuery <= 1.3.2 behavior.
    if ( traditional === undefined ) {
        traditional = jQuery.ajaxSettings && jQuery.ajaxSettings.traditional;
    }

    // If an array was passed in, assume that it is an array of form elements.
    if ( jQuery.isArray( a ) || ( a.jquery && !jQuery.isPlainObject( a ) ) ) {
        // Serialize the form elements
        jQuery.each( a, function() {
            add( this.name, this.value );
        });

    } else {
        // If traditional, encode the "old" way (the way 1.3.2 or older
        // did it), otherwise encode params recursively.
        for ( prefix in a ) {
            buildParams( prefix, a[ prefix ], traditional, add );
        }
    }

    // Return the resulting serialization
    return s.join( "&" ).replace( r20, "+" );
};
```

Note that these are copied directly from [the source for v1.11.0](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.js).

I believe that the `XMLHttpRequest.send()` function expects data in the querystring format, but jQuery accepts a javascript object and converts it for you.